# Example for dependent name lookup in case when noexcept-specification is needed but not instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, noexcept, name-lookup

From cppreference:

> When the noexcept-specification of a function template specialization is needed, but hasn't yet been instantiated, the dependent names are looked up and any templates used in the expression are instantiated as if for the declaration of the specialization.

Could someone provide some example(s) of this?

What names can be looked up here (is there necessarily ADL involved, or is it e.g. just plain dependent type names that have to be looked up themselves)?

I have a hard time understanding what the above means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically means that when the noexcept-specification is *needed* (which is a specific term), it is instantiated. And when it's instantiated, it's instantiated in the same way that function template declarations are instantiated - including everything that has to happen for that.

The cppreference example has:

```
template<class T> T f() noexcept(sizeof(T) < 4);
decltype(f<void>()) *p; // error
```

Even though we're not evaluating `f`, the *noexcept-specification* of it is *needed* (because `f` is selected by overload resolution and would be odr-used if it were evaluated). So at that point it is instantiated. But that instantiation is an error because `sizeof(void)` is ill-formed.

On the other hand, this slightly modified version is ok:

```
template<class T> T f(int);
template<class T> T f() noexcept(sizeof(T) < 4);
decltype(f<void>(1)) *p; // ok
```

We never instantiate `f()`'s noexcept-specification because it is not needed.

There is nothing special with respect to name lookup. It's just the normal template rules apply, so:

```
struct N {
    struct X { };
    void h(X);
}
void h(int) noexcept;
template<class T> void g(T t) noexcept(noexcept(h(t))
```

When the *noexcept-specification* of `g` is needed, that's to instantiate `h(t)` - which may or may not perform ADL as usual. `noexcept(g(0))` would be `true`, but `noexcept(g(N::X{}))` would be `false`.

Additionally, any relevant templates are only instantiated when they are *needed*. So if we had:

```
template<class T> struct X;
template<class T> T f() noexcept(X<T>::value);
template<class T> T f(int);
```

`X<T>` will only be instantiated when that *noexcept-specification* is needed, not before. So `decltype(f<int>(0))` will not try to instantiate `X<int>`, but `decltype(f<int>())` would be a hard-error because `X<int>` is an incomplete type so `X<int>::value` is ill-formed.